# log every function call without infinite recursion in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created function that have to log every function call.

```
(function () {
  var oldCall = Function.prototype.call;
  var newCall = function(self) {
    Function.prototype.call = oldCall;
    console.log('Function called:', this.name);
    Function.prototype.call = newCall;
    this.apply(self, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }
  Function.prototype.call = newCall;
})();
```

But it fails to stackoverflow:

```
Function called: slice
Function called: slice
Function called: slice
Function called: slice
Function called: slice
Function called: slice
Function called: slice

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How to modify it to make it work?
I guess the problem is that `slice` is function too and it calls infinite recursion. Maybe it is possible to filter like:

```
if (functionName == 'slice')
{
    return;
}
```

But cannot figure out how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add before applying the call:

```
 if (this.name == 'slice')
 {
     return;
 }
```

to get:

```
(function () {
 var oldCall = Function.prototype.call;
 var newCall = function(self) {
 if (this.name == 'slice')
 {
     return;
 }

 Function.prototype.call = oldCall;
 console.log('Function called:', this.name);
 Function.prototype.call = newCall;
 this.apply(self, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
 }
 Function.prototype.call = newCall;
})();
```

But its not a full solution because in my code I'm stuck at "TypeError: undefined is not a function".
Checking this, self and arguments for undefined does not help :-(.

Comment: The Function which produces the error (not original but by having this solution for logging function calls) was filter and now it is the join function from path module which uses also Array.prototype.filter.call which is now undefined X-). So this is not realy a good solution sorry...